# Is it possible to use a table in the database when it is NOT a Django model?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible get a queryset from a table in the app database that is NOT a model in the app?

If I have a table that is not a model named "cartable", conceptually, I want to do this:

```
myqueryset = cartable.objects.all()
```

Is there a relatively easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, django ORM is tied to django models, if you don't have models, ORM doesn't know how to work it out. Why don't you create a model for it then?

Comment: I actually want to dynamically create a small table from a larger table for a specific instance, then delete it after I have aggregated those data and added the results of the aggregation to a model (the aggregation on the smaller table happens multiple times, but in slightly different ways). I tried aggregating on a queryset and it was SLOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you would need to create a class (not a model), with methods that use raw SQL. You should see more details here on how to do so: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Please note that you will have to manually create the object with the right properties afterwards.

If you wanted to use Django ORM without the models, I don't think it is possible. You could however create a model that matches your db in a separate app and never create migrations for it to ensure you don't accidentally modify the DB.

Comment: This appears to be working well for me. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access an existing table in your database that is not managed by your application, you can still create a class for it, and tell django to ignore it for migrations.

Just create a model and add the fields you need to access and then add a meta class to tell django to leave it alone.

```
class MyModel(model.Model):

   class Meta:
      managed = False
```

you can read about that at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: Actually I want to create and delete the tables, so I don't think I can do it this way, but I may need this in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, "not really". Django QuerySet deals with model instances, so everything in QuerySet API is tied into models. Everything expects to return model instances, uses model fields etc.

That said, you should be able to create a model for an existing table. You will need to add db_table to the Meta, so Django knows where the table lives. If you have some indexing, you will need to make sure Django's idea of indexes is the same as the one in the database. indexed=True on fields and unique_together in Meta should help a lot with that.

Comment: I want to be able to create and delete the tables so I don't think this will work for me but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: In that case you are stuck with using SQL directly. As I said, all of Django ORM API expects models and model instances. You can try to generate model classes dynamically, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I had good success with the SQL...I was actually replacing a MySQL stored procedure so it was pretty easy for this particular app. Because I was already putting the results of the SQL back into a Django model before I tried to use them, I think the raw SQL was the best solution.