# Django multiple databases with same models but different data

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-database

I want to implement a warehouse system. This system will have many queries (about 100k data/model a year.  To maintain the performance, I want to use different database for different year (the data is mutually exclusive so its okay to connect to a database at a time). Is there a way to have multiple databases that can be dynamically changed (and dynamically created, if possible) with all databases have same models.

Comment: "about 100k data/model a year" that's nothing

Comment: Why do you think this would lead to better performance? There are probably simpler ways to improve your db performance issues.

Comment: is django fast enough to query ~10m data in <0.1s?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to put this in a comment, so I will put it here.

I have an app where I have a relatively large base table. I want to run some statistics on small subsets of data. Based on user input (which provides information to make the subset), I use raw SQL to create the subset and perform the statistics, and then I copy the results into a model (also using raw SQL). At first, I tried to perform annotations, but it was slow ([Is it possible to use a table in the database when it is NOT a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501534/is-it-possible-to-use-a-table-in-the-database-when-it-is-not-a-django-model)). I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do or why, but I found working with the raw SQL was a good way to dynamically create subsets (tables and/or views), and move data in and out of a Django model.